# How to authenticate to sharepoint from a c# console application?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, shared-libraries

I need to create a folder in SharePoint and upload files (pdf, excel, word, etc) into my SharePoint folder from a C4 .net application. I found many articles which are using the username and password to log in. The SharePoint site I need to access has SSO enabled. I did some research and could not find any good articles which explain how authentication has to be performed.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is a "C4.net" application? This aspect may be important to suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application should never use user credentials to authenticate. In this ecosystem, there exists an object call an Azure AD Application, associated with a Client ID and Client Secret (or Certificate). You can use these credentials to connect to any *authorized* site and do actions.

A quick google search gave me this nice article that does this quite nicely:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/token-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/